# How to prevent notification from opening an activity or removed when clicked in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am developing an Android app. I my app, I am trying to show process notification to user. But what I want is I do not want notification opening an Activity or removed when it is get clicked. What I am doing is I am showing notification when a user click a button. Notification will saying "Transferring data". Notification is fired from receiver.

So when user click a button, receiver is called. But I do not want that notification removed or closed when user click it. I do not want to show any activity as well. I just want to close itself when data processing finish.

This is my receiver that show notification when button is clicked

```
public class GalleryImageUploadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context context;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder notification;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context pContext, Intent intent) {
        this.context = pContext;
        showProcessNotification();
        doAsyncTaskInBackground()
    }

     public void doAsyncTaskInBackground()
     {
         //I want to close it here after task is finished
     }

    public void showProcessNotification()
    {
        try{

            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            notification.setAutoCancel(true);
            notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification.setTicker("Transferring data...");
            notification.setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            notification.setContentTitle("Transferring data...");
            notification.setOngoing(true);
            notification.setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT);
            Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);//In this line, I do not want to open any activity
            i.putExtra("start", OfficeMainActivity.FRAGMENT_NOTIFICATIONS);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(),0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(context.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify(1,notification.build());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }


    }


    public void uploadImages(Context context,Intent intent)
    {
        onReceive(context,intent);
    }
}
```

Receiver is called in button click event like this

```
GalleryImageUploadReceiver receiver = new GalleryImageUploadReceiver();
        receiver.uploadImages(getBaseContext(),new Intent());
```

As you can see, I set ongoing to true because I want to make it undismissable. But the problem is it is closed because an activity is opened.

These are what I want:

1. I do not want to open an activity when notification is clicked.
2. I only want it close itself. How can I do that?
3. Instead can show option dialog with buttons?

Comment: Do not call setContentIntent method. To not dismiss onClick, use setAutoCancel(false)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But I do not want that notification removed or closed when user click it.

remove this

```
notification.setAutoCancel(true);
```

> I do not want to open an activity when notification is clicked.

remove this

```
Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);//In this line, I do not want to open any activity
i.putExtra("start", OfficeMainActivity.FRAGMENT_NOTIFICATIONS);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(),0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

I suggest you read up on notification documentation. This is pretty straightforward stuff.

> How can I close if self please?

you can "close" a notification manually with

```
nm.cancel(1); // if 1 is your notification id.
```

> Instead can show option dialog with buttons?

Instead of doing that you should just present the buttons inside the notification.

Comment: Hi @Tim I have Question if setAutoCancel(boolean autoCancel) is used to 
 dismisse notification automatically when the user touches it(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html). so if user toches then it will fire intent or not?

Comment: @roman_empire it will fire an intent only if you use `setContentIntent` to instruct it to do so. It is not related to `setAutoCancel`

Comment: I understand now Thank you

Comment: How can I close if self please?

Comment: Besides, I added question 3. Please can I have answer for it as well. Thank for your support.